# Get the percentage of row with TEXT type

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, average, sql-null

I am trying to calculate the percentage of the row events when the value is null. I have a table with 2 rows (zip_code, events).

```
TABLE weather
  events TEXT
  zip_code INTEGER
```

This is the query I wrote. I am just getting the count of all the events of every zip_code that are null:

```
SELECT zip_code, COUNT(*) AS percentage
FROM weather
WHERE events IS NULL
GROUP BY zip_code, events;
```

This is my output:

```
zip_code percentage
94041        639
94063        639
94107        574
94301        653
95113        638
```

I want to covert it into percentage, but I don't know how to get the total of events so I can do something like this COUNT(the events that are null)*100/COUNT(ALL).

Comment: See `count(*) over()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the aggregate function `AVG()` for the boolean expression `events IS NULL` which evaluates to `0` for `false` and `1` for `true`:

```
SELECT zip_code, 
       AVG(events IS NULL) * 100 AS percentage
FROM weather
GROUP BY zip_code;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/1JzLAnFt).

Answer (score 1):

Two things.

1. You need to know the total number of rows to get a percentage.
2. When doing this, don't group by `event`.

This should do it.

```sql
SELECT zip_code, 
       100.0 * (SUM(events IS NULL)) / COUNT(*)) AS percentage
FROM weather
GROUP BY zip_code;
```

`SUM(events IS NULL)` is MySQL-specific syntax, because MySQL Boolean expressions such as `events IS NULL` evaluate to either `1` or `0`. To be portable you'd write it  `SUM(CASE WHEN events IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`.

By the way, if you can use a `VARCHAR()` type in place of `TEXT` you'll get better performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE table #tblNulls 
(
    zip_code INTEGER,
    Nullcount integer
)

CREATE TABLE #tblAll
(
    zip_code INTEGER,
    Allcount integer
)

INSERT INTO #tblNulls
SELECT zip_code, COUNT(*) AS Nullcount 
FROM weather
WHERE events IS NULL
GROUP BY zip_code, events;


INSERT INTO #tblAll
SELECT zip_code, COUNT(*) AS Allcount 
FROM weather
GROUP BY zip_code, events;


SELECT a.zip_code, a.Allcount,n.Nullcount , n.Nullcount/a.Allcount
FROM #tblAll a
LEFT JOIN #tblNulls n ON a.zip_code = n.zip_code
```